# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus with Functions

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Please excuse the weird title. I was unsure about how to summarize this.

So lets say we have this integral:

$ \int_{kx}^{cx} t^2 dt = f(x)$

If we wanted to apply $f(x)$ with $2x$ instead of $x$ then would the integral bound change like so: 
$ \int_{2xk}^{2xc} t^2 dt = f(2x)$

or

$ \int_{2x}^{2x} t^2 dt = f(2x)$

**Edit:**

If the above is true, then would differentiating f result like so: 
$-(2xk)^2 + (2xc)^2 = f'(2x)$

Comment: what is wrong with the result? Please explain your problem a little bit more detailed.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I'm just asking to confirm if what I have is right.

Comment: I've updated for clarity.

Comment: In your last integral you have both your bounds being $2x$; is this okay? I mean, wouldn't that integral be $0$ for all $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(2x)=\int_{2xk}^{2xc} t^2 dt$

But the derivative is wrong, since the boundaries of the integral both contain the variable $x$.

The lower bound must be constant to apply the rule that you applied, i.e. $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt = f(x)$$

But instead you can use this  $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{g(x)}^{f(x)}h(t)\,dt=h(f(x))\cdot f'(x)-h(g(x))\cdot g'(x) $$